# Alterar texto do menu item accelerator

Tags: javafx, java-8

Criei o seguinte `MenuItem`,

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Alterar");
KeyCodeCombination acc = 
                     new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
item.setAccelerator(acc);
```

Ocorre que no resultado o acelerador aparece como `Control+←` e eu gostaria que fosse exibido `Control+Enter`.

Como faço para alterar o texto que é exibido no acelerador, especificamente o enter.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]